# Thread : Crashed: com.apple.NSURLSession-work

Tags: ios, ios8, nsurlsession, cfnetwork

With the release of iOS 8 we've started getting several types of crashes that we've never seen before.  Wondering if anyone else has seen this or has any suggestions.

Several of them look similar to this:

```
Thread : Crashed: com.apple.NSURLSession-work
0  libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x2fd3adfc __pthread_kill + 8
1  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x2fdb8d37 pthread_kill + 62
2  libsystem_c.dylib              0x2fcda909 abort + 76
3  libsystem_malloc.dylib         0x2fd6b3af szone_error + 334
4  libsystem_malloc.dylib         0x2fd6b637 free_small_botch + 66
5  CFNetwork                      0x21a63935 HTTPMessage::ensureParserFinished() + 72
6  CFNetwork                      0x21a7aad3 HTTPMessage::copyHeaderFieldValue(__CFString const*) + 18
7  CFNetwork                      0x21b43e87 HTTPSniffing::checkRequestAndUpdateResponseForSniffingPurposes(_CFURLRequest const*, _CFURLResponse*) + 130
8  CFNetwork                      0x21b15ddd URLConnectionClient::_loaderClientEvent_DidReceiveResponse(_CFURLResponse*) + 340
9  CFNetwork                      0x21b1b7d9 ___ZN19URLConnectionLoader26protocolDidReceiveResponseEP14_CFURLResponse_block_invoke + 24
10 CFNetwork                      0x21ac9e03 ___ZN20ClassicURLConnection21withLoaderClientAsyncEU13block_pointerFvP21LoaderClientInterfaceE_block_invoke + 14
11 CFNetwork                      0x21b14ca9 ___ZNK25URLConnectionInstanceData18withWorkQueueAsyncEU13block_pointerFvvE_block_invoke + 12
12 libdispatch.dylib              0x2fc548cb _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 10
13 libdispatch.dylib              0x2fc5c651 _dispatch_queue_drain + 952
14 libdispatch.dylib              0x2fc5709d _dispatch_queue_invoke + 84
15 libdispatch.dylib              0x2fc5dba1 _dispatch_root_queue_drain + 320
16 libdispatch.dylib              0x2fc5ecd7 _dispatch_worker_thread3 + 94
17 libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x2fdb5e31 _pthread_wqthread + 668
```

Thanks,
Dan

Comment: Do you use AFNetworking?

Comment: Yes, we use AFNetworking.

Answer (score 1):

This is a bug in Apple's code and there is nothing you can do about it, other than wait for an iOS update (or you may want to avoid using the NSURLSession APIs and invoking -[NSURLHTTPResponse allHeaderFields]). But don't hold your horses, it's been there since at least iOS 7.0 and has been reported multiple times (I have done it and my ticket got closed as dupe) and is still not fixed on iOS 8.0.2.

Comment: Were you able to reproduce it?

Comment: No, it just happened from time to time on iOS 7 on my code that was using NSURLHTTPResponse objects, but it seems to be a lot more frequent now on iOS 8 apparently due to the NSURLSession stuff making heavier use of the CFNetwork code responsible for the crash. Possibly triggered by some sort of race condition? That'd explain why it is not a deterministic crash.

Comment: Interesting...I just got bit by this in iOS 8.1.2, so still not fixed.

Answer (score 1):

Try updating to the latest AFNetworking 2.5.3.

Comment: still reproduce it on iOS 11.0.3 - 11.3.0 with AFNetworking 3.0.0

Comment: We no longer have the crash in our app. So they may have fixed the issue for some things but still have it in other ways.